# What is the fundamental group of this space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Question: Calculate the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^n$ minus the $n$ hyperplanes with coordinates .

My attempt is the following:

Firstly, my understanding of the space in the question is that it is the space $\mathbb{C}^n - \bigcup_{i=1}^n \lbrace (x_1,..,x_{i-1}, 0, x_{i},..,x_n), x_j \in \mathbb{C}  \rbrace $.

This space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^* \times ...\times \mathbb{C}^*$ and since  the fundamental group of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, then the fundamental group of the space in question is isomorphic to $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z} $. Is this true ?

Comment: Yes, as pointed spaces, the complement is equal to $(\mathbb{C}-\{0\})^n$, and  for pointed spaces $(X,x)$ you seem to already know that $\pi_1(X^2,(x,x))\cong \pi_1(X,x)$.

Comment: @JuliusJ. you probably mean $\pi_1(X^2,(x,x))\simeq\pi_1(X,x)^2$.

Comment: It is is isomorphic to the **product** of $n$ copies of $\mathbb Z$.